# c# TextBox custom wrapping

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, word-wrap

I have `TextBox` and multiline string, for example:

```
var str = "First: q1=42, w2=sometext, q3=false\r\nSecond: some very very very very very111 very very very very long text text.";
```

And `TextBox` have small `Size.Width`. If I paste `str` into `TextBox.Text`:

```
|First: q1=42, w2=sometext, q3=false  | <- that is end of TextBox rectangle
|Second: some very very very very     | <- 
|very111 very very very very long text| <- text autowrapping to start of textbox area
| text.                               | <-
```

I want that:

```
|First: q1=42, w2=sometext, q3=false  | <- that is end of TextBox rectangle
|Second: some very very very very     | <- first line normal
|        very111 very very very very  | <- offset text after wrapping
|        long text text.              | <- on ("Second: ").Length points
```

At least, offset on const value (may be `'\t'` or 3 whitespaces).

Comment: You are not going to get that out of a TextBox control. The best you can do is manually insert those tabs.

Comment: How can I calculate length of part of `str` (in pixels)? I dont know where insert tabs

Comment: If you think is hard to do now then you probably haven't considered how much harder it will be when the user starts editing the content of the textbox :)  Use RichTextBox instead, its SelectionHangingIndent property ought to help.

Comment: If you use a fixed width font like courrier you could use a fixed width. split the string on spaces. Concatenate the words one by one while adding up the word lengths. When a word doesn't fit on the line, add a newline and three spaces.

Comment: I use no fixed font